# What is the most Pythonic way to handle unicode strings in code that runs in both 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'm writing code which must work on both 2 and 3, and occasionally have to deal with utf-8 strings.

Consider the following on 2.x:

```
>>> mystr = 'Nyår'
>>> mystr_u = mystr.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This will work on 3, but will raise a UnicodeError in 2.x because of the differences between what the str object actually is.

This is obviously problematic when code must work in both versions.

How I am currently getting around this is with the following:

```
>>> mystr = 'Nyår'
>>> try:
...     mystr_u = mystr.encode('utf-8')
... except UnicodeError as e:
...     mystr_u = mystr
... 
>>> mystr_u
'Ny\xc3\xa5r'
```

This seems a little messy to me. Is there a more Pythonic way to make my code version-independent when it comes to utf-8 strings?

Edit: Just to clarify, I am not working with literals in the actual code. That was just done for the example. The actual code is getting the string from another call, such as os.listdir() on a directory with entries using unicode characters.

Comment: Never ever call `encode` on a `str` in Python 2.x. (There are exceptions, but if you don't know those exceptions, just learn this rule of thumb until you run into one of them—which may well be never, given the lifespan f Python 2 at this point.)

Comment: [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?](https://youtu.be/sgHbC6udIqc)

Comment: @wwii thanks, I'll watch this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to work in Python 3.0-3.2, the simple answer is to use explicitly-unicode string literals, like this:

```
mystr = u'Nyår'
```

In Python 2.7, this means the literal is a `unicode` instead of a `str`. In Python 3.4+, it's ignored, because literals are already `str` (which is Unicode) by default.

And now you can use it as Unicode, or `encode` it to UTF-8 (which will give `str` in 2.x and `bytes` in 3.x), or whatever else you want, and it will work consistently.

Also, if this is a literal in a module's or script's source code, make sure to add an encoding declaration to the file—the default isn't UTF-8 until Python 3.5. And of course make sure to actually save the file as UTF-8 in your editor.

---

If you do need to work with 3.2, there is no ideal option. The best choices are to use [`six.u`](http://six.readthedocs.io/#binary-and-text-data) to fake it (at some cost in performance on 2.x, and in error handling if you screw up the encoding declaration), or to use `2to3` plus `modernize` instead of a static codebase.

---

If you're looking for a way to handle the string *type* rather than literals, you may want to use `six`, or just do something like this at the top of your code:

```
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    unicode = str
```

And then, if you're writing a library function that should take both unicode and bytes and do different things accordingly, you can write code that works properly in both 2.x and 3.x, like:

```
def func(s, default_encoding='utf-8'):
    if not isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.decode(default_encoding)
    # now use s knowing it's unicode
```

Comment: let's say `mystr` is a parameter of a function. How can it be encoded inside the function?

Comment: @codekaizer What do you mean? If it's not a literal, there isn't a problem in the first place. Just pass around `unicode`/`str` objects everywhere in your code except the edges, and `decode`/`encode` from/to `str`/`bytes` at those edges.

Comment: In the actual code, it is not a literal, it is the return value of some other call, namely, a directory listing. The problem still persists.

Comment: @jesse_galley This is why Stack Overflow asks for a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem you want to solve, so we don't waste each other's time talking past each other.

Comment: @jesse_galley Anyway, the answer to that is what I told you earlier: wrap things up at the edges of your code (like where you call `listdir`) so you immediately `decode` bytes as they come in and `encode` to bytes as they go out, and use Unicode consistently in the middle. The `func` in my answer is an example when your edges are a library for other code to call; when it's the other way around, just put the `if not isinstance…` bit around the `for fname in os.listdir(path):` instead.

Comment: @abarnert respectfully, I did assign the literal to a var and specifically state I was working with string objects, I accept some of the responsibility for being unclear, and apologize for that, but it was not a safe assumption that I was asking about literals exclusively, as evidenced by the very first comment on your answer.  Anyway, is it your opinion that the most Pythonic way to deal with this is to use  if/else blocks testing for unicode instances? because that seems quite a bit more verbose than my current implementation of swallowing an exception.

Comment: also, I understand that this answer is somewhat subjective in nature, but "what's more Pythonic" questions are not uncommon on S.O.  I will likely accept your answer, but do want to read any other suggestions that you/others might have.

Comment: @jesse_galley Generally, the Pythonic answer is to isolate the difference to the edges of your program. Usually those edges are just a few lines of input and output code, so an `if` test around those lines is the simplest solution. If you have a whole API surface, it may be better to abstract that out—e.g., decorate all of your functions with a converter that wraps args outputs in that `if` test—but it’s still going to be there somewhere (unless you can change your API to demand that the other side use `unicode` in py2, in which case it’s their problem rather than yours).

Comment: @jesse_galley You may also want to read the Unicode HOWTO and the relevant entries on Nick Coghlan’s blog. You won’t get a direct “do this or else” answer that’s more specific than what I’ve written, but you will get a lot more depth than you can get in an SO comment.

Comment: Also, while this is _usually_ the Pythonic answer, there are some cases where “work in whichever one is `str` is the right answer, or “work in UTF-8 everywhere even in py3”, or even “litter all of your code with `if` tests so every function can take both bytes and Unicode” or “write two parallel APIs, one of which is rarely used in py2 and the other rarely in py3 and unit test the hell out of it to make sure they’re equivalent”. Hopefully you don’t have one of those cases.

Comment: @abarnert thankfully, no, I do not have one of those precarious cases. In fact, handling it at the edge is what I'm doing now, with the exception method in my question. In fact, I (seemingly) only have the one point in the code where encoding matters, and that's when I'm hashing the string with hashlib, as hashlib.append() only accepts an encoded value.  I'm mostly concerned whether or not my exception-swallowing method itself is less Pythonic than something else (such as an if/else), not about the general structure of the code. Thanks for the reading suggestions, I'll check them out.

Comment: @jesse_galley OK, cool. Exception swallowing is a bad idea in this case because of 2.x's behavior when you call `encode` on something that's already a `str` (decoding it with your default encoding so it can re-encoding it). Usually you get lucky and this raises a `UnicodeDecodeError`, but it can silently produce mojibake instead. But I do see the appeal of `try`/`except` here, and I have seen at least one project that wrote a wrapper function to hide the `if`/`else` for 2.x and `AttributeError` for 3.x and wrap them both in a new `UnicodeError` subclass.